# Changing zoom level in the maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am writing a javascript which will change the zoom of the map corresponding to some events in the map. I am animating in the map, and I want to change the zoom levels at specific instances and then back to where it satrted from.
Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
map.panToBounds((new google.maps.LatLngBounds((new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)),(new google.maps.LatLng(1,1)))));
```

Just use the `panToBounds` function from the `google.maps.Map` class.

It will zoom into the rectangle created from those 2 points.

If you do want to do it without the location use the `setZoom` function of the `google.maps.Map` class so it will look like this:

```
map.setZoom(5);
```

Comment: Thank you .  I used the setZoom function, but with a button, The button works, but the zoom doesn't change

Comment: And then i would go ahead to use panToBounds function after setZoom starts working and seek your help if it doesn't work out